# iPhone: connecting to multiple networks

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi, adhoc

I'm currently working on a project that requires the iPhone to connect to another device using an Ad-Hoc network (WiFi). Simultaneously, I require a connection to the internet in order to upload data to a server also using WiFi.

My question is: is the iPhone capable of connecting to multiple networks?

If not, is it possible (and viable) to switch between networks assuming the data rate is low? For example, iPhone receives data via Ad-Hoc, disconnects, connects to other WiFi network, established connection with server, sends data, disconnects from network, reconnects to Ad-Hoc network etc?

Answer (score 0):

If the data rate is low and you are talking to another iOS device, check out [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html).
This is Bluetooth, though.

I have not seen a way to connect to multiple wi-fi networks simultaneously.